# Is this a correct approch of finding expected runtime of an algorithm?

Tags: runtime-analysis, average-case

Consider two algorithms; we analysis their run time only by counting the number of comparisons

```
TwoMax1(A):   
     S = negative infinite
     L = negative infinite
     loop through the array A
         if A[i] > L:
             S = L
             L = A[i]
         else
            if A[i] > S
                S = A[i]
    return (L,S)



 TwoMax2(A):   
     S = negative infinite
     L = negative infinite
     loop through the array A
         if A[i] > S:
            if A[i] > L:
             S = L
             L = A[i]
            else
                S = A[i]
    return (L,S)
```

Here is my approach for the first algorithm:

(1) define our sample space. Since the returned output is a pair, maximum and second maximum could be anywhere in the array. For each maximum, there are $(n-1)$ possible index for second maximum, and we have $n$ possible index for the maximum value; So sample space: $S = \{(A[0],A[1]),(A[0], A[2]),(A[0],A[3]),\dots\}$ and so on.

Define an indicator $I_i = 1$ iff $A[i] > \max \{A[0], A[1], \dots, A[i-1]\}$.

The total expected comparison of comparing to maximum would be $$\mathbb{E} (\sum_{i=0}^n I_i) = \sum_{i=0}^n \mathbb{E}(I_i) = \mathrm{Prob}(A[i] > \max \{A[0], A[1],\dots, A[i-1]\}) = \frac{n+1}{2}.$$

where $$\mathrm{Prob}(A[i] > \max \{A[0], A[1], \dots, A[i-1]\}) = \frac{i}{n}$$ because under the sorted array, we have $\frac{i}{n}$ chance of choosing a integer that greater than $A[0], A[1],\dots,A[i-1]$.

Now similar, the total expected comparison of comparing to second maximum would be same; and we sum two parts together up is $n+1$.

Is this a good way of approaching? If so, I also want to know some other ways of doing it, for example, define a different random variable to solve the second function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that in `TwoMax1`, $A[i]$ is *always* compared to $L$. This already gives you $n$ comparisons. If $A[i]$ is not the current maximum, then it is compared to $S$. This happens with probability $1-1/i$ (see below). Therefore the total expected number of comparisons is
$$
n + \sum_{i=1}^n \left(1 - \frac{1}{i}\right) = 2n - H_n = 2n - \log n - \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$

In `TwoMax2`, $A[i]$ is *always* compared to $S$. Again, this gives you $n$ comparisons. If $A[i] > S$, which happens when $A[i]$ is one of the two maximal elements, then $A[i]$ is compared to $L$. When $i = 1$, it is always the case that $A[i] > S$, and otherwise it happens with probability $2/i$. Therefore the expected number of comparisons is
$$
n + 1 + \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{2}{n} = n + 2H_n - 1 = n + 2\log n + \gamma - 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$

The second algorithm thus makes roughly half as many comparisons than the first algorithm.

---

You mention that the sample space consists of all *outcomes*. But in fact, the sample space consists of all *inputs*, or in your case, all input permutations. You are analyzing the algorithm with respect to the uniform distribution over this sample space.

Also, the probability that $A[i] > A[1],\ldots,A[i-1]$ (numbering elements from zero) is not $i/n$ (consider for example the case $i=1$!) but rather $1/i$. The reason is that if $A[1],\ldots,A[n]$ is a random permutation then $A[1],\ldots,A[i]$ is a random permutation of $\{A[1],\ldots,A[i]\}$. In particular, $A[i]$ is a random element of $\{A[1],\ldots,A[i]\}$, and so it equals the maximum with probability $1/i$.

Comment: thanks so much, this is very helpful; so every time when I'm dealing with expected runtime; I consider the sample space as the set of all possible input. Based on the input, I calculate the runtime for each one; then there will be a distribution over all possible inputs; finally, I use expectation function; is there anymore similar type of questions that can get me to practice ?

Comment: Your description is accurate. I recommend checking out the average time analysis of Quicksort.